# What does Update() in ITK

Tags: itk

I'm new to `ITK`. I just want to ask, what does `Update()` mean? For example, I found that I had to use it with an `ImageFileReader`. Why is that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it updates the filter (or in your case) image source. Which means that it makes sure the requested image region is up to date by executing the processing pipeline. The ITK Doxygen of, for example, the ProcessObject explains this procedure.